# How can I make my code to work with both listview and recyclerview

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview

I have created a frgament that works with listview and gridview I want it to work with RecyclerView as well. The frgament detects the end of list/grid and makes an api call to fetch the next page.

Answer (score 0):

All i had to do is use the adapter pattern so my fragment can work with both types of list